# Removing elements from a string within a list

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x

I have a list consisting of dictionaries converted to string, each slot in that list is as follows
'{< Candidate: Candidate1 >: 1.5}'

I want to remove all non-alphanumeric and ':' elements, so they look like this:

'Candidate: Candidate1: 1.5'

I tried to do the following:

```
for l in list:
        for l2 in l:
                if l2.isalnum()==False or l2==':':
                        l2.replace("")
```

But I did not get the desired result, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> li=[ '{: 1.5}',  '{: 1.6}']
```

You can use a element by element regex:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'[^\w\d.]+',"",e) for e in li]
['1.5', '1.6']
```

---

Edit

If you want to keep the `:` you can do:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'[^\w\d.:]+',"",e) for e in li]
[':1.5', ':1.6']
```

Comment: I get it, but I do no want eliminate the ":" , what is need add or eliminate from this regex?

Comment: The items inside of `[^\w\d.]+` are the things being kept and anything that is NOT `\w` (a-zA-Z_) `\d` (0-9) or a literal `.` are being eliminated. Put anything you want to keep inside the brackets. If you want to keep `:` add than inside of  `[^\w\d.]+`.